# Imported address:private key

Tags: blockchain

Please I want to ask how can I get the private key so to withdraw from my imported address and is it possible that you get to pay a certain amount of btc to get the private key..thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

You are the victim of a scam. Please don't send anymore money to the scammers and in future read about how bitcoin works before you put your money into it.

Answer (score -1):

That's not through.. you don't need to pay to get private key. You can get your private key from the root of ur wallet address host such as blockchain,  coinbase, bitcoin dtcom. If you have remember your password / Phrase text recovery.